# Can you insert a newline in between pipes in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, instead of:

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | grep -v '^PATH'| grep -v '^USER'
```

is there a way to do

```
( set -o posix ; set ) 
| grep -v '^PATH' 
| grep-v '^USER'
```

within the .sh script itself (in order to make the code cleaner and easier to read?

Comment: Simply: `grep -v '^\(USER\|PATH\)' < <(set -o posix;set)`

Answer (score 6):

Put the pipe at the end of the line instead of the beginning

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | 
    grep -v '^PATH' | 
    grep -v '^USER'
```

or escape the newlines

```
( set -o posix ; set ) \
    | grep -v '^PATH' \
    | grep -v '^USER'
```

If you use the second method, make sure there's no whitespace after the backslash, it has to be right before the newline.

Note that there's no need to use two `grep` calls. Use `grep -E` with a regexp that matches both variables.

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | grep -E -v '^(PATH|USER)'
```

Comment: Thanks!! Both options work well. Much obliged

Comment: @Roadowl I just cut pasted the commands without looking at them, since they're irrelevant to the question.